# Django Microservices authentication

Tags: django, microservices, django-database

I was reading about Microservices in django , and came to know in Microservices we keep small services separately and they can operate individually . if I am not wrong about this concept how I will validate using JWT token from a user from one Database to use that in 2nd Microservices ? ?

Answer (score 8):

In typical JWT concept you have auth server(**AC**) and multiple resources servers(your domain µservices), and flow looks like:

- client (aka **clientA**, frontend for example) sends request to AC for jwt token (for example *POST* to */authenticate* with username and password)
- when **clientA** was authenticated **AC** returns jwt token
- **clientA** sends request to some resource on your µservice (aka **µserviceA**) with jwt token in header ("*Authorization: Bearer ...*")
- **µserviceA** sends request to **AC** to confirm that token is valid, if so,
  µserviceA can accept request from your client and handle it

Your **clientA** may also be another µservice. Your µserviceA knows the user's roles from jwt token (after decoding) and simply can block request when roles are not appropriate.